# Nullable List Parameter in .Net Core 3.1 Web API

Tags: c#, parameters, asp.net-core-webapi, nullable, .net-core-3.1

Hi I have the following route in my web api:

```
[Route("Resource/")]
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Get([FromQuery] IEnumerable<string> filterItems = null)
{
}
```

In .Net Framework 4.8, whenever I would call this without specifying any `filterItems` it would default the `IEnumerable` to `null` which is the behaviour I'm looking for.
After migrating to .Net Core 3.1, I now get an empty list instead.

Anyone know how I can default the nullable list to null (`= null` works with any other type, but lists seem problematic)?

Comment: It is by design,if you want to check if the list is null,you can check if  `filterItems.count` is 0.

Comment: Conceptually it's not the same thing though. One is having to filter on 0 items and the other one is not having a filter at all.

Comment: @YiyiYou Would you know of a way to change that default behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use a custom model binding.Here is a demo:
Action:

```
[Route("Resource/")]
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Get([ModelBinder(typeof(CustomBinder))]IEnumerable<string> filterItems)
{
}
```

CustomBinder:

```
public class CustomBinder : IModelBinder
    {
        public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
            if (bindingContext == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bindingContext));
            }
            List<string> model=new List<string>();
            var l = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("filterItems[0]").FirstValue;

            if (l != null)
            {
                int i = 0;
                while (bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("filterItems[" + i + "]").FirstValue != null)
                {
                    model.Add(bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("filterItems[" + i + "]").FirstValue);
                    i++;
                }
                bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(model);
            }
            else
            {
                bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(null);
            }
            
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
```

result:
[image]

Comment: Okay, I get this. But does this remove the ability to specify an empty list? What I would like is the ability to pass a "null" list, as well as any empty list.  How might that be done?

Comment: @AlexDresko is correct; this moves the problem to now not being able to have empty lists if defined empty.

Comment: @UnLuckyNiko I looked into this again recently and couldn't find a good solution. To me, what makes the most sense, is that all lists are non-null and empty by default. You can pass a list of items the normal way: ?filterItems=something&filterItems=another&...`. But if you want a null list, you should be able to say `?filterItems=null`.  `null` becomes the single magic string that allows a list to be null. OR, lists are null by default, and you could `?filterItems=empty` if you want an empty, non-null list.  I've just never taken time to do it.